# How to inject system property into static bean in configuration?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, static-initialization

In my Spring `@Configuration` class I wish to inject the system property `${brand}` into a static String bean called `brandString`. I have succeeded doing that with the workaround described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19622075/1019830 using `@PostConstruct` and assigning the static field an instance field value injected through `@Value`:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Value("${brand}")
  private String brand;
  private static String brandString;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    brandString = brand;
  }

  @Bean
  public static String brandString() {
    return brandString;
  }

  // public static PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {...}
```

Is there another way of statically inject the value of `${brand}` into the `brandString` field, without the workaround using another "copy" `brand` and a `@PostConstruct` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    private static String brand;

    @Value("${brand}")
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        AppConfig.brand = brand;
    }

    @Bean
    public static String brandString() {
        return brand;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Great! How does that work really, setting the `@Value` annotation on the setter method?

Comment: how did you select the method name for a @Bean method??